# Modal not opened properly programmatically in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I'm using `ng-bootstrap` modal

import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

On button click it is opened properly

```
<button class="btn labelbtn accountbtn customnavbtn"(click)="demobutton(UploadModal)" type="button">   Open   </button> 


demobutton(UploadModal:any) {
   
    this.modalService
      .open(UploadModal, {
        windowClass: "modal",
        ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title",
        backdrop: false,
      })
      .result.then(
        (result) => {},
        (reason) => {}
      );
   
  }
```

but when i try to open through function it is not opening properly only some of the divs are visible content is not visible.

```
async open(files){
      this.modalService.dismissAll();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.demobutton('UploadModal'); 
      }, 2000);
```

Any solution Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function timeout(ms) {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => 
     {this.demobutton('UploadModal');}, ms));
}

async open(files){
     this.modalService.dismissAll();
     await timeout(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See that when you have a button (I imagine you open a template) you write: `demobutton(UploadModal)`. "UploadModal" is a "template", not a string. See the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModal): "Content can be provided as a TemplateRef or a component type."

So you need "get" the template using ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('UploadModal') modal:TemplateRef<any>

//and use, see that you open "this.modal"
this.modalService
      .open(this.modal, {
        windowClass: "modal",
        ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title",
        backdrop: false,
      });
```

**Update** demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7y98mj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-basic.ts)